# Alter array of objects into array with co-ordinates for chart

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

Learning JavaScript. I need to plot some data (I'm using Nivo).

I have data from my API in the format of:

```
[{"as_at_date":"2020-02-21","value":815202269.5,"num":139},{"as_at_date":"2020-02-25","value":809209302.32,"num":139},{"as_at_date":"2020-03-12","value":723686212.35,"num":139},{"as_at_date":"2020-03-13","value":734798809.24,"num":139},{"as_at_date":"2020-03-16","value":701366943.2,"num":139},{"as_at_date":"2020-03-17","value":710833514.89,"num":139},{"as_at_date":"2020-03-18","value":699154469.83,"num":139},{"as_at_date":"2020-03-19","value":694649684.34,"num":139},{"as_at_date":"2020-03-20","value":685400033.9,"num":139}]
```

To plot a line chart with Nivo I need to alter the above array into:

```
    [{"id": 'XXXXX",
"data": [{"x":"2020-02-21","y":815202269.5},{"x":"2020-02-25","y":809209302.32},{"x":"2020-03-12","y":723686212.35},{"x":"2020-03-13","y":734798809.24},{"x":"2020-03-16","y":701366943.2},{"x":"2020-03-17","y":710833514.89},{"x":"2020-03-18","y":699154469.83},{"x":"2020-03-19","y":694649684.34},{"x":"2020-03-20","y":685400033.9}]
```

- Ignore "num" property.
- nest the data and create an "id"
- Change as_at_date to "x", value to "y"

Last attempt was trying to use .map like `.map(item => [{"x": item['as_at_date']}, {"y": item['value']}])` but wasn't quite right.

Appreciate any help, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would use [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to create the nested data first. Then adding `id` and `data` properties to the final object.

Try the following:

```js
const data = [{"as_at_date":"2020-02-21","value":815202269.5,"num":139},{"as_at_date":"2020-02-25","value":809209302.32,"num":139},{"as_at_date":"2020-03-12","value":723686212.35,"num":139},{"as_at_date":"2020-03-13","value":734798809.24,"num":139},{"as_at_date":"2020-03-16","value":701366943.2,"num":139},{"as_at_date":"2020-03-17","value":710833514.89,"num":139},{"as_at_date":"2020-03-18","value":699154469.83,"num":139},{"as_at_date":"2020-03-19","value":694649684.34,"num":139},{"as_at_date":"2020-03-20","value":685400033.9,"num":139}];

const nested = data.reduce((a, c) => a.concat({x: c['as_at_date'], y: c['value']}), []);

const result = {
  id: 'XXXXX',
  data: nested
};

console.log(result);
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

`map` is certainly the way to go.

Here's my approach:

```js
const data = [{"as_at_date":"2020-02-21","value":815202269.5,"num":139},{"as_at_date":"2020-02-25","value":809209302.32,"num":139},{"as_at_date":"2020-03-12","value":723686212.35,"num":139},{"as_at_date":"2020-03-13","value":734798809.24,"num":139},{"as_at_date":"2020-03-16","value":701366943.2,"num":139},{"as_at_date":"2020-03-17","value":710833514.89,"num":139},{"as_at_date":"2020-03-18","value":699154469.83,"num":139},{"as_at_date":"2020-03-19","value":694649684.34,"num":139},{"as_at_date":"2020-03-20","value":685400033.9,"num":139}];

function reformattedData(arr) {

  // Destructure only the required properties
  return arr.map(({ as_at_date, value }) => {

    // And just return those values in a new object
    // using the new property names
    return { x: as_at_date, y: value };
  });
}

const out = { id: 'xxx', data: reformattedData(data) };

console.log(out);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your attempt was almost correct, just omit the surrounding `[]`:

```js
const input = [{"as_at_date":"2020-02-21","value":815202269.5,"num":139},{"as_at_date":"2020-02-25","value":809209302.32,"num":139},{"as_at_date":"2020-03-12","value":723686212.35,"num":139},{"as_at_date":"2020-03-13","value":734798809.24,"num":139},{"as_at_date":"2020-03-16","value":701366943.2,"num":139},{"as_at_date":"2020-03-17","value":710833514.89,"num":139},{"as_at_date":"2020-03-18","value":699154469.83,"num":139},{"as_at_date":"2020-03-19","value":694649684.34,"num":139},{"as_at_date":"2020-03-20","value":685400033.9,"num":139}];

const outputData = input.map(item => ({ x: item.as_at_date, y: item.value }));

console.log(outputData);

const result = {
  id: 'XXXX', // create your id here,
  data: outputData,
};
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one

```
const array = [{"as_at_date":"2020-02-21","value":815202269.5,"num":139},{"as_at_date":"2020-02-25","value":809209302.32,"num":139},{"as_at_date":"2020-03-12","value":723686212.35,"num":139},{"as_at_date":"2020-03-13","value":734798809.24,"num":139},{"as_at_date":"2020-03-16","value":701366943.2,"num":139},{"as_at_date":"2020-03-17","value":710833514.89,"num":139},{"as_at_date":"2020-03-18","value":699154469.83,"num":139},{"as_at_date":"2020-03-19","value":694649684.34,"num":139},{"as_at_date":"2020-03-20","value":685400033.9,"num":139}];

const formatted_array = input.map((item) => {
return {x: item.as_at_date, y: item.value}});

const final_data = {
  id: 'XXXX',
  data: formatted_array ,
};
console.log(final_data);
```